# How to profile building?

Tags: c++, build, profiling

I am working on a large (~1 mloc) C++-application which takes too long to build from source (on windows using Visual Studio, on the mac using a Makefile or XCode). I would like to know where to start optimizing (e.g. precompiled headers, forward declarations, ...).

As with performance of the application itself, I would like to profile the build process before I start optimizing.

What tools are available to support this?

Comment: The fastest fix for slow build times (or atleast a help) is switching to SSDs and more RAM, maybe even using RAM disks.

Comment: already applied, but still too slow ;)

Comment: a milli lines-of-code is not much... SCNR

Comment: Looks like both answers so far are trying to carefully suggest: get rid of Windows :)

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, please state exactly which version of Visual Studio you're using. If possible, upgrade to VS2010 as this has much better support for parallel building.  Here's several things to consider:

- Put the source tree on a different disk to the system disk. If you can extend to 2 SSDs (1 for system, 1 for source) then this makes a *huge* difference
- Enable parallel builds. In VS2010 this halved our build time for a project about the same size as yours. Enable the 'Multiprocessor compilation' switch (/MP). You may find that one or two of your projects may need this turned off if they have strange dependencies, but as long as it's on for most projects then you'll get a massive boost.
- VS2010 has verbose build timing logging options which can help you isolate the time spent in different projects. VS2005/2008 have a build timing option
- If you have VS2005 or VS2008 then try out the [MPCL](http://todobits.es/mpcl.html) plugin (it's not free but very cheap) which will do better parallel building than VS itself. If you have the budget there are tools like Incredibuild
- If you're using Makefiles then use the `-j` flag to parallelise. If you're using Xcode then you can use distributed builds if you have other macs available (I've never had any luck with this myself though)
- You could look into using [ccache](http://ccache.samba.org/) with gcc
- Enable Precompiled headers for all or most projects. It may take a bit of experimenting to work out how much benefit you get -- you do hit diminishing returns quite quickly the more you put in them (and the more you have in, the more rebuilds you'll need to do)
- Read John Lakos's book on [Large Scale C++ Design](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Large-Scale-C-Software-Design-APC/dp/0201633620/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1343384126&sr=8-1) which is a fantastic source of advice for how to split up large projects to isolate dependencies
- Consider a two-stage build process. If you have lots of third party libraries that need to be built, or other libraries that don't change all that often then set up a separate project for them. Try building that in parallel with your main project or save the binaries. Consider checking the binaries into your source control system (yes, I know checking binaries into SCM is generally considered evil, but I believe you have to be pragmatic)

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways of improving build-times. One of them is of course more hardware, i.e. faster disks and more RAM. Another is features of the compiler like precompiled headers. There are also external tools that can help, like [distcc](http://code.google.com/p/distcc/) or [ccache](http://ccache.samba.org/). For GNU make, there is also the `-j` option to run several make processes in parallel.